# BlackJack Program in python gets error when run

Tags: python

```
import cards

class BJ_Card(cards.deck):
    """ A Blackjack Card. """
    ACE_VALUE = 1

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.is_face_up:
            v = BJ_Card.RANKS.index(self.rank) + 1
            if v > 10:
                v = 10
        else:
            v = None
        return v

class BJ_Deck(cards.Deck):
    """ A Blackjack Deck. """
    def populate(self):
        for suit in BJ_Card.SUITS:
            for rank in BJ_Card.RANKS:
                self.cards.append(BJ_Card(rank, suit))


class BJ_Hand(cards.Hand):
    """ A Blackjack Hand. """
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BJ_Hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ":\t" + super(BJ_Hand, self).__str__()
        if self.total:
            rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"
        return rep

    @property
    def total(self):
        # if a card in the hand has value of None, then total is None
        for card in self.cards:
            if not card.value:
                return None

        # add up card values, treat each Ace as 1
        t = 0
        for card in self.cards:
              t += card.value

        # determine if hand contains an Ace
        contains_ace = False
        for card in self.cards:
            if card.value == BJ_Card.ACE_VALUE:
                contains_ace = True

        # if hand contains Ace and total is low enough, treat Ace as 11
        if contains_ace and t <= 11:
            # add only 10 since we've already added 1 for the Ace
            t += 10

        return t

    def is_busted(self):
        return self.total > 21


class BJ_Player(BJ_Hand):
    """ A Blackjack Player. """
    def is_hitting(self):
        response = games.ask_yes_no("\n" + self.name + ", do you want a hit? (Y/N): ")
        return response == "y"

    def bust(self):
        print(self.name, "busts.")
        self.lose()

    def lose(self):
        print(self.name, "loses.")

    def win(self):
        print(self.name, "wins.")

    def push(self):
        print(self.name, "pushes.")


class BJ_Dealer(BJ_Hand):
    """ A Blackjack Dealer. """
    def is_hitting(self):
        return self.total < 17

    def bust(self):
        print(self.name, "busts.")

    def flip_first_card(self):
        first_card = self.cards[0]
        first_card.flip()


class BJ_Game(object):
    """ A Blackjack Game. """
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.players = []
        for name in names:
            player = BJ_Player(name)
            self.players.append(player)

        self.dealer = BJ_Dealer("Dealer")

        self.deck = BJ_Deck()
        self.deck.populate()
        self.deck.shuffle()

    @property
    def still_playing(self):
        sp = []
        for player in self.players:
            if not player.is_busted():
                sp.append(player)
        return sp

    def __additional_cards(self, player):
        while not player.is_busted() and player.is_hitting():
            self.deck.deal([player])
            print(player)
            if player.is_busted():
                player.bust()

    def play(self):
        # deal initial 2 cards to everyone
        self.deck.deal(self.players + [self.dealer], per_hand = 2)
        self.dealer.flip_first_card()    # hide dealer's first card
        for player in self.players:
            print(player)
        print(self.dealer)

        # deal additional cards to players
        for player in self.players:
            self.__additional_cards(player)

        self.dealer.flip_first_card()    # reveal dealer's first

        if not self.still_playing:
            # since all players have busted, just show the dealer's hand
            print(self.dealer)
        else:
            # deal additional cards to dealer
            print(self.dealer)
            self.__additional_cards(self.dealer)

            if self.dealer.is_busted():
                # everyone still playing wins
                for player in self.still_playing:
                    player.win()
            else:
                # compare each player still playing to dealer
                for player in self.still_playing:
                    if player.total > self.dealer.total:
                        player.win()
                    elif player.total < self.dealer.total:
                        player.lose()
                    else:
                        player.push()

        # remove everyone's cards
        for player in self.players:
            player.clear()
        self.dealer.clear()


def main():
    print("\t\tWelcome to Blackjack!\n")

    names = []
    number = games.ask_number("How many players? (1 - 7): ", low = 1, high = 8)
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        names.append(name)
    print()

    game = BJ_Game(names)

    again = None
    while again != "n":
        game.play()
        again = games.ask_yes_no("\nDo you want to play again?: ")


main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I'm importing the following file 
But get this error class BJ_Card(cards.deck):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given) This is my first time having to write a program and have spent sometime fixing other issues but this one I just cant figure out. Please help.

```
import random


# Deck of cards - first letter represents the face value and
# second letter represents the suit
deck = ['AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
        'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
        'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS',
        'AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC']

# Playing deck in use
playing_deck = []


# Function to determine whether there are any cards left in the
# deck of playing cards
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: True if the deck is empty, False otherwise
def is_empty_deck():

    # Check to see whether playing deck is empty
    return len(playing_deck) == 0


# Function to rebuild and shuffle the deck
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: Nothing is returned from the function.
def reset_deck():
    global playing_deck

    # Create new playing deck
    playing_deck = deck.copy()

    # Shuffle deck
    random.shuffle(playing_deck)


# Function to deal one card
# Parameters: No parameters
# Returns: A string (containing two characters) representing
# the card delt, i.e. '2H' meaning 2 of Hearts
def deal_one_card():

    # Check to see whether there are any cards left
    if is_empty_deck():

        # Rebuild and shuffle deck
        reset_deck()

    # Return a card (string of two characters)
    return playing_deck.pop(0)
```

Comment: In `self.cards.append(BJ_Card(rank, suit))` you initialize class `BJ_Card` with 2 arguments, but it seems the class `BJ_Card` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you don't have a `__init__` method in your  `BJ_Card(cards.deck)` class.

Also, you're trying to init new object of card by calling

```
self.cards.append(BJ_Card(rank, suit))
```

when BJ_Card doesn't accept neither `rank` nor `suit`

try this:

```
class BJ_Card(cards.deck, rank, suit):
    """ A Blackjack Card. """
    ACE_VALUE = 1
    super(cards.deck, self).__init__('''whatever you need to pass here ''')

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.is_face_up:
            v = BJ_Card.RANKS.index(self.rank) + 1
            if v > 10:
                v = 10
        else:
            v = None
        return v
```